# How many layers and neurons on the layers does a neural network need for for sales prediction?

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design, prediction, hidden-layers

The inputs (features) and expected output for my ANN are these:

- Input 1: Product id (number, cast to double)
- Input 2: Year in the past (1900..2017, cast to double)
- Input 3: Month of year (1..12, cast to double)
- Expected output: Sale of month (number of units sold, cast to double)

I need to predict the sale of a product for a certain month in a certain year. **How many layers and how many neurons on there layers should I put**?

Comment: Figure it out through trial and error. You don't have a lot of inputs, so you should not make it to big. I think having two hidden layers is enough, with a maximum of 10 neurons per hidden layer. But what have you tried? Because you have such a small input/output it would be fairly easy to figure it out yourself through trial and error...

Comment: i have 12 training samples for the 12 months of last year * 1 product. I use this shape [10,10,1], but the training doesn't converge after 30,000,000 sample iterations

Comment: Have you tried using an LSTM?

Comment: never tried LSTM before, may be because of something wrong in my own ANN code, i'll try some libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every answer you get is just an opinion, it is based on experience.
My answer is a single hidden layer of 5 neurons.

Besides, I recommend you to use a TWEANN system (Topology and Weight Evolving ANN).

Such system applys genetic algorithm to search and optimize an ANN with the optimal topology and weights.

Take a look at [NEAT](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/neat_software/) and [DXNN](https://github.com/CorticalComputer/DXNN2).